# Optimal Mean Reversion Trading with Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, finance, brownian-motion

### **TL;DR:**

I'm getting a very different answer when trying to solve the problem described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5062.pdf) using a different approach (which seems simpler to me).

I probably have some error in my reasoning but I'm just not seeing where. Can anyone spot my error?

---

### **The problem:**

Consider an investor holding an asset whose price is modelled by an [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Definition) process $X_t$ driven by the SDE

$$\text{d}X_t = \theta(\mu − X_t) \text{d}t + \sigma \text{d}Bt$$

with $\mu$ (long-term mean), $\sigma, \theta > 0$.

For a given initial price $x$, if the investor sells the asset at time $t$ then the expected present value of the proceeds of her sale is given by
$$v(t; x) = \mathbb{E}[{e^{−r t} (X_t − c)}|X_0=x]$$

where $r$ is her rate of borrowing and she incurs transaction costs $c \ll \mu$.

Given the initial price $x$, the investor is interested in finding the maximum present value $V(x)$ she can expect to attain if she times the sale optimally. That is,

$$V(x) = \text{sup}_{t \in T} \, v(t; x)$$

where $T$ denotes the set of all stopping times with respect to the filtration generated by $X_t$.

**How can we find $V(x)$?**

---

### **The paper's solution:**

The full details are [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5062.pdf), but the punchline is that:

$$
V(x) = \begin{cases}
    (b^∗ − c) \frac{F (x)}{F (b^∗)} & \text{if } x \lt b^∗\\
    x − c              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

where $b^*$ is the optimum liquidation price and found by solving

$$F(b) = (b − c)F′(b)$$

for $b$ and where
$$F(x)=\int_0^\infty u^{\frac{r}{\theta} - 1} e^{\sqrt{\frac{2\theta}{\sigma^2}}(x - \mu)u - \frac{u^2}{2}} \text{d}u$$

Notice in particular that $V$ depends on $\sigma$ (since $F$ depends on $\sigma$).

---

### **My attempted solution**:

By [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Mathematical_properties), we begin by rewriting $v(t; x)$ more explicitly as:
$$v(t; x) = e^{-rt} (x e^{-\theta t} + \mu(1 - e^{-\theta t})) \hspace{2cm} (1)$$

Now we can write the first and second order conditions (FOC, SOC) for maximising $v$ over $t$:

\begin{align}
\text{FOC: } \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} v(t; x) &= \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} e^{-rt} \left(x e^{-\theta t} + \mu(1 - e^{-\theta t})\right)\\ &= e^{- (r + \theta)t} \left((\mu - x) (r + \theta) -  r(\mu - c) e^{\theta t}\right) \\&= 0\\
\text{SOC: }\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2} v(t; x) &= e^{- (r + \theta)t} \left(r^2 (\mu - c) e^{\theta t} - (\mu - x) (r + \theta)^2\right) \\&< 0
\end{align}

By rearranging the SOC we see that for a maximum to exist we must have that
$$
\mu - x > \left(\frac{r}{r + \theta}\right)^2(\mu - c) e^{\theta t} \hspace{2cm} (2)
$$
Therefore, depending on the value of $x$, we have two cases:

**Case 1: a maximum exists**

If $(2)$ is satisfied then we may solve the FOC for $t$ which yields:

$$t^* = \frac{1}{\theta}\text{log}\left(\frac{(\mu - x)(\theta + r)}{r (\mu - c)}\right)$$

Subsituting $t^*$ into $(1)$ leads us to:

\begin{gather*}
V(x) = v(t; x) \Bigr\rvert_{t = t^*} = \theta\left(\frac{\mu-c}{r+\theta}\right)^{1+\frac{r}{\theta}}\left(\frac{\mu-x}{r}\right)^{-\frac{r}{\theta}}
\end{gather*}

This is very different to the solution the paper gives.

**Case 2: no maximum exists**

If $(2)$ is not satisfied, then we have $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} v(t; x) < 0$:
$$
\mu - x \leq \left(\frac{r}{r + \theta}\right)^2(\mu - c) e^{\theta t} \implies \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} v(t; x) \leq  - \frac{r \theta}{r + \theta} (\mu - c) e^{- r t} < 0
$$

In other words, $v(t; x)$ is decreasing in $t$ and so the investor should sell immediately and receive
$$V(x) = x - c$$

Notice in both cases $V$ does not depend on $\sigma$.